# Add header to output

Tags: powershell

I have a file like this;

```
vserver      volume            snapshot-policy
------------ ----------------- ---------------
vs1          vol1              default
vs1          vol2              daily
vs2          logs              none
vs2          home              hourly
```

My command `get-content my_file |? {$_ -match "none"}`  returns one record, that's fine. But I would like add heading to the output. How do I format the output to add heading like below?

```
vserver      volume            snapshot-policy
------------ ----------------- ---------------
vs2          logs              none
```

Comment: How did you produce/obtain this file in the first place? Much easier to work with a CSV file than a tabular file format like your example

Comment: Mathias is correct (of course). While you can manipulate the text file to get the results you want, it would be infinitely more powerful to get the source data in a format such as CSV which could then be more easily/consistently loaded by PowerShell as an object.

Comment: Thanks Mathias..but this output go a into bigger output like text file, I prefer to use this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to get a specified number of results from a collection. In this case we can use it to return the first two lines of the file as follows:

```
$file = get-content my_file
$header = $file | select -first 2
```

We could also then use it to exclude the header from our search by using `-Skip`:

```
$content = $file | select -skip 2
```

You could then use it as follows:

```
$result = $content |? {$_ -match "none"}

if ($result) {
    $header
    $result
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Mark Wragg.

Comment: It worked in the morning now I am getting this error. +         $header = get-content $file | select -first 2
+                               ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: Are you sure you meant to do `$header = get-content $file | ..` and not `$header = $file | ..`. If you've followed my answer then $file already contains the contents of the file.

Comment: My section 
       Invoke-NcSsh "vol show -type RW -fields snapshot-policy" >$outfile2
              $file = get-content $outfile2
  $header = get-content $file | select -first 2
  $content = get-content $file |select -skip 2
  $result = $content |? {$_ -match "none"}
  If ( $result ) {
     $header
     $content
  }

Comment: You only need to use get-content once, after that just use $file.

Comment: As an aside, you are making this harder than it needs to be by outputting it to a text file and then reading it back in. You should be able to simplify the whole thing to `Invoke-NcSsh "vol show -type RW -fields snapshot-policy" | where snapshotpolicy -eq none`

Comment: Thanks Gents..I ended up with code;
$NoSnapshotPolicy = Invoke-NcSsh "vol show -type RW -fields snapshot-policy" |%{$_ -replace ' ',";"} |ConvertFrom-csv -Delimiter ';' -Header vserver, volume, snapshotpolicy | where snapshotpolicy -EQ "none"
    If ($NoSnapshotPolicy) {

        write-host "There is/are volume(s) with no snapshot policy, please check" -ForegroundColor Yellow
   
     $NoSnapshotPolicy
 
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt" | select -skip 2 | %{$_ -replace '  +',";"} | 
ConvertFrom-csv -Delimiter ';' -Header vserver, volume, snapshotpolicy | where snapshotpolicy -EQ "none"
```